# Error occur when I install Hplip 3.18.3

Tags: printing, hplip

I hope that someone can help me.

I have tried to install hplip 3.18.3 for my HP Photosmart 3210 printer. But in the meantime I found out that it requires snmp which I tried to install. It seems that snmp has been installed with succes - but hplip 3.18.3 couldn't use it. I got the error "configure: error: cannot find net-snmp support (or --disable-network-build)"

For downloading and installing snmp I have used the guide on https://www.maketecheasier.com/net-snmp-part-1/ 
For downloading and installing hplip I have used the guide on https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/install/manual/distros/ubuntu

Best regard
Michael Eriksen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't understand why you are going to compile hplip from source.

[Official hplip](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index) page says:

> HP PhotoSmart 3210
>   Min. HPLIP Version - 0.9.5 |

All you need is to install `hplip` from repository ([3.14 and up](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=hplip-gui)):

```
sudo apt-get install hplip-gui
```

After installation you can launch HP utility from terminal as `hp-toolbox` or from GUI as *HPLIP Toolbox*. It does not need proprietary plugin.

Comment: You can [mark answer as accepted](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) if it solved your problem.